# Trying to deallocate a dynamic array of std::forward_list pointers (C++)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to deallocate a dynamically allocated array of pointers to forward lists that was created with something like:

```
deck = new forward_list<T>*[numDecks];
for (int i = 0; i < numDecks; i++) {
    deck[i] = new forward_list<T>;
}
numberOfDecks = numDecks;
```

I tried to iterate and delete the decks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numDecks; i++) {
    delete[] deck[i];
    numberofDecks--;
}
delete[] deck;
```

But I got a read access violation. In fact, even if I just write:

```
delete[] deck[0];
```

I still get a read access violation. I've been playing around with this for quite some time and haven't been able to get it to work. I'm attaching a screenshot of the error (it appears in the forward_list file.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: This question's shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You should [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Why would you allocate a forward list dynamically?

Comment: Unfortunately, not my decision.

Comment: There are very few, can't think of any of the top of my head, cases in which allocating a C++ library container with `new` is the best option. You may have found one, but you should edit the question and expand on your use case so we can understand it. With understanding we can better help you find alternatives or a smarter way to deal with the bad hand you've been dealt.

Comment: Many times a new programmer thinks they need a dynamic allocation because they need to pass a pointer and not realize they could take and pass the address of an automatically allocated object.

Answer (score 1):

`delete[]` is for deleteing something that was allocated via `new []`. When you allocated something via `new` you need to delete it via `delete`.

There is no apparent reason for any manual dynamic allocations in your code. The `std::forward_list` already manages the memory of its elements. Storing pointers in the list has no advantage unless you need a level of indirection for some reason. And if you need it you should use smart pointers not raw ones. Also allocating the `std::forward_list` itself dynamically is most likely not needed (and again: use smart pointer if you do).

Answer (score 1):

Your code has *undefined behavior*, as you are creating the `std::forward_list` objects using `new` but then destroying them with `delete[]` instead of `delete`. You need to change this:

```cpp
delete[] deck[i];
```

To this:

```cpp
delete deck[i];
```

`new`/`delete` are for single objects, and `new[]`/`delete[]` are for arrays. They must be matched up properly.

A better option is to use `std::vector<std::forward_list>` instead of `std::forward_list*[]`, and let the `vector` handle the memory for you.